Brake problems (need adjustment too often)
I've been having problems with my bicycle brakes for not a short time and I've been having it with a couple different bikes. The brakes get loose after 1-2 weeks. I deliver with my bike so I use it 50-75 kms every day. I don't know how to adjust it so I have to pay a bike shop each time and it's a little bit pricey and overwhelming. Do you have any suggestion what I can do or why it happens? (Both hydraulic and non hydraulic brakes)

It sounds like you are having different problems on different bikes. It's difficult to offer a good answer without more detail. Please ask one question per brake type and include as much detail as possible.

Brakes should absolutely not "come loose" after  500-750 km of riding.   Can you show us in photos how they are loose?  Or are they wearing out?  Do you do a lot of hard braking while riding?

e-bike or non-assisted bicycle? how heavy are you (broad number)? are you delivering in a hilly city or a city with many arched bridges?


I don't know how to adjust it

There are a lot of resources in the internet how to adjust brakes (and how to fix anything on a bicycle), in real life you may be lucky in asking help at the local bike co-op (US thing, I suspect) or getting in touch with the local cyclist associations (in Europe you are likely to find the contacts at the European cyclist federation).
I totally understand you are a bit conservative in dealing with them (you do not want to have a bicycle with no brakes). However, take one afternoon of time to play around watching video and guides on the internet and your brakes.
You probably need some tools (have a look for some good quality tools, because good tools lasts forever and you can use them for other things than your bicycle), but in general these are not bicycle-specific tools (hex keys, screwdrivers).
We humans are kind of primates and we can learn a lot by watching and repeating the movements.
